# Parse XML Array with SimpleXmlConverterFactory / Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, xml-parsing, retrofit2

How can I parse an Array of XML Elements "echeance" form this XML format:

```
<data>
    <code>353</code>
    <city>Ville</city>
    <echeance ech="3">
        <subData>45</subData>
    </echeance>
    <echeance ech="6">
        <subData>45</subData>
    </echeance>
    <echeance ech="9">
        <subData>45</subData>
    </echeance>
</data>
```

I want this data to be parsed in a Data object containing an array of "Echeance" objects, using *SimpleXmlConverterFactory*

For now, i have this kotlin code :

```
data class Data(val ville :String, val code :Int) {

    @get:Element(name="city")
    lateinit var city :String

    @get:Element(name="code") var remoteCode :Int = -1

    @get:ElementArray(name="echeance") lateinit var echeances :Array<Echeance>
}

class Echeance {

    @get:Attribute(name="ech") var value :Int = 0
    @get:Element(name="subData") var value :Int = 0 

}
```

Unfortunately, i cannot change the XML format, for example to embed "echance" nodes in a parent "echeances" node.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer !

I have to annotate my Echeance class as

```
@Root(name = "echeance")
```

then remove the name attribute for my @ElementList echeances and mark as *inline*

```
@field:ElementList(inline = true, required = false) lateinit var echeances :List<Echeance>
```

the full code :

```
data class Data(val ville :String, val code :Int) {

    @field:Element(name="city")
    lateinit var city :String

    @field:Element(name="code") var remoteCode :Int = -1

    @field:ElementList(inline = true, required = false) lateinit var echeances :List<Echeance>

}

@Root(name = "echeance")
class Echeance {

    @field:Attribute(name="ech") var value :Int = 0
    @field:Element(name="subData") var value :Int = 0 

}
```